# Map through JSON data from API return undefinded

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Hello I am trying to map through data from API like this :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import { getAllActiveJobs } from "../../backend/controllers/apiHandler"

const ForAnsatte = () => {
  const [activeJobs, setActiveJobs] = useState([])
  const init = () => {
    getAllActiveJobs().then((data) => {
      setActiveJobs(data)
    })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    init()
    return () => {}
  }, [])


  return (
    <Layout>
      {activeJobs.data
        ? activeJobs.data.map((item) => {
            return <div key={item.jobId}>{item.candidateId}</div>
          })
        : "Loading..."}
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default ForAnsatte
```

But then I get this error :  TypeError: activeJobs.data.map is not a function

API return JSON object which looks like this :

[image]

Could someone help me point out what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The data returned from the api seems to be a JSON object and map() works only for arrays.

I'd suggest looping through the JSON object using Object.keys(activeJobs.data).forEach()

Answer (score 1):

`data` is not an array. It is an object!
I think you should something like this,

```
Object.keys(activeJobs.data).forEach((e) => {
   console.log(activeJobs.data[e])
})
```

and render it like this,

```
return ( <Layout> {
        activeJobs.data ?
        Object.keys(activeJobs.data).map((item) => {
                return <div key = {
                    activeJobs.data[item].jobId
                }> {
                    activeJobs.data[item].candidateId
                } </div>  }): "Loading..."
            } 
          </Layout>
        )
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: How I can render this data in JSX?

Comment: `Object.keys(activeJobs.data).map((item) => {  return <div key={item.jobId}>{item.candidateId}</div>  })` Something like this

Comment: But when I do this I don't have anything, nothing is rendered. What I need is to get data from API, and render them to the user.

Comment: `Object.keys(activeJobs.data).map((item) => {  return <div key={activeJobs.data[item].jobId}>{activeJobs.data[item].candidateId}</div>  })` Does this work?

Comment: No , still nothing is rendered. But also there is no any error.